# finding the surface where curve is given as geodesics

Tags: differential-geometry

the parametric equation of the following curves can be given by

(1) Astroid :-$(a \cos^3 t , a \sin^3 t)$
(2) Cardioid:- $(a(2\cos t-\cos 2t), a(2\sin t-\sin 2t))$
(3) Deltoid :- $(2a\cos t+a\cos 2t , 2a\sin t-a\sin 2t)$

Can someone tell are there any surfaces in which they becomes geodesics of the surfaces. thanks for your precious time.

Comment: Before that shall I add to your list a simple (0) Circle:- $( a \cos t , a \sin t )?$

Comment: To me the question appears vague without a unique answer. If a surface is given we can find a geodesic. But if a geodesic is given then it can form a part of many sets of surfaces.

Comment: E.g., given is a straight line segment in 3d. Now rotate it around any axis. You get a hyperboloid of 1-sheet, Give it a uniform or non-uniform twist/torsion around an arbitrary line forming helical surface sets... such as a Moebius strip etc.

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

a) All cylindrical  surfaces "vertically extruded" by parameter $u$ are  (trivial) examples .

(1) Astroid cylinder :-$(a \cos^3 t , a \sin^3 t, b u ) = ( X(t),Y(t), b u ) $
(2) Cardioid cylinder :- $(a(2\cos t-\cos 2t), a(2\sin t-\sin 2t, b u ))$
(3) Deltoid cylinder :- $(2a\cos t+a\cos 2t , 2a\sin t-a \sin 2t, b u)$

b) All surfaces of revolution obtained by rotating through angle $u$ on one of above axes $X(t),Y(t)$  which make up the meridians.

$$ (X(t) \cos u, X(t) \sin u, Y(t) ) $$

and to it we may also add helices

$$ (X(t) \cos u, X(t) \sin u, b u  ) $$

HINT2:

For a particular metric (  E, F are functions of u, v only ) example that is not a surface of revolution,

$$ ds^2=(1+u^2)~ du^2 + 2 uv~ du ~dv + (1+v^2) ~dv^2 $$
we can work out from canonical geodesic equations  where c is a constant,
$$u+v=c$$

A simple $ (u,v)$ relation on arc s

$$ u= \frac{s}{\sqrt{2+c^2}},~ v= c-\frac{s}{\sqrt{2+c^2}}$$
Hope you take it further with simple parametrization in 3-space

Comment: yes, thats true. But did there any other except the surface of revolution